# C++ how to use emplace_back for user defined structure

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to make use of emplace_back for my user defined structure:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct IDNumber
{
    IDNumber(std::vector<int> d) : id(d){}
    std::vector<int> id;
};
struct Def
{
    Def(std::initializer_list<int> id) : mid(id){}
    IDNumber mid;
};

struct Student
{
    std::vector<Def> ent;
};

int main()

{
 Student a;
 a.ent.emplace_back({ {2000} });
}
```

I get compilation issues:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<EntryDef>::emplace_back'
```

Comment: Your first argument to your constructor is `std::initializer_list<int>` yet you pass `{ {2}, 1 }`?

Comment: I tried to change the line - a.ent.emplace_back({2,1,2}, FType::FD_NONE, Fmt::FMT_NONE, RWProp::PROP_RO, FId(0,TTypes::TYPE_NONE)); - but still I get the compilation issue - am I missing something?

Comment: `emplace_back` is function template which tries to deduce the types of arguments.  an initializer list does not have a type, so deduction fails. Use `std::initializer_list<int>{ 2, 1 }`.

Comment: @CoryKramer what is wrong with list-initializing the first int?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki yeah, they kind of messed up `initializer_list`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53302655/c-how-to-use-emplace-back-for-user-defined-structure#comment93486166_53302655) by [@PiotrSkotnicki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3953764/piotr-skotnicki):

> `emplace_back` is function template which tries to deduce the types of arguments. an initializer list does not have a type, so deduction fails.

Clarifies the problem.

An alternative way to "fix" this issue is to pass an rvalue of the needed type as argument of the constructor, instead of the initializer list:

```
EntryDef(ID &&id, FType ft, … ) : mid(std::forward<ID>(id)), ftype(ft), … {}
```

Called as:

```
Def a;
a.ent.emplace_back(ID{ 2, 1 }, FType::FD_NONE, …);
```

Live example [HERE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/nT8Tluv5eoc6pXYY).